# How to crowdsource behaviour across > 100.000 humans while each human only solves a very short task (< 10 sec)

Tags: methodology, internet, mechanical-turk

I'd like to carry out a behavioural experiment that involves humans classifying a very simple image into one of two classes and there is no right or wrong answer. For the question of the study it is important that each image is classified by a different human (more or less). In other words: each human would only be presented an image once (or at least only a few times) and in total more than 100.000 humans would be involved.

This makes it difficult to use e.g. MTurk, as each "task" would only take < 10sec and the payout would be 5ct / image at best. Human-in-the-loop services such as scaleapi.com or figure-eight.com are usually based on a few thousand workers, meaning that each human would likely see many images.

The optimal service would be a kind of CAPTCHA system that is open to research experiments. I also vaguely remember there was a gaming company that sold in-game "mini-games" for crowdsourcing behaviour, but I am unable to find it. And suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: what's the rationale behind the having each participant solve it once or only a few times? for example, could you have them solve no more than one per day instead?